# Question related to commutative ring being Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and $A = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$. I want to prove the following:

> If $A$ is a Noetherian ring, then so is $A_{f_i}$ (which is the ring $A$ localized at $f_i \in A$). If each $A_{f_i}$ is Noetherian, then $A$ is Noetherian.

It says in the exercise to use the hint $A \rightarrow \prod A_{f_i}$ is injective, but I am not sure how this is useful... I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of the $A_{f_i}$?  Thanks.

Comment: edited it! Thanks!

Comment: Gotcha.  And thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the following:

> **Claim:** If $A$ is a commutative ring with $A=(f_1,...,f_n)$, then an $A$-module $M$ is finitely generated if and only if each localization $M_{f_i}$ is finitely generated.

In your situation, you can apply this to $M := I$ since in this case $M_{f_i} = I_{f_i}$ is finitely generated over $A_{f_i}$ as a submodule of the - by assumption - Noetherian $A_{f_i}$-module $A_{f_i}$.

Since this is an exercise, do you want to try proving the claim for yourself? If you have trouble, I already typed it and can show it if you want. Use the assumption to find a finite set of elements of $M$ which generates each of the localizations $M_{f_i}$ and deduce that it must already generate $M$.

Comment: This is a special case of the following: If $A$ is a commutative ring with $A=(f_1,...,f_n)$, then an $A$-module $M$ is *zero* if and only if each localization $M_{f_i}$ is *zero* (which is simpler to prove).

Comment: Yes true, that's what one has to prove, but I intentionally didn't state that as I didn't want give too many hints.

Comment: @Hanno I will try it myself first! Thank you! btw by "using the assumption" do you mean the hint given?

Comment: @Hanno When you say each localization $M_{f_i}$ is finitely generated, does it mean finitely generated as $A_{f_i}$ module or $A$ module?

Comment: @user201886: Oh sorry, I mean as an $A_{f_i}$-module

Comment: @Hanno Thanks! So I thought I figured it out, but I don't seem to use the hint "$A \rightarrow \prod A_{f_i}$ is injective"... So maybe I am missing something? Do you use this fact?

Comment: @user201886: No, I agree with user26857 in that I don't know where to use that.

Comment: @Hanno Ok. Thank you very much!